# How to make Selenium webdriver's cursor exit a text area

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use Selenium to create a omegle chat bot, not one that sends a message and DC's but one that trys to continue a conversation with a person for as long as it can. One issue I've ran into is that omegle interprets having the cursor in the textArea as typing so it will continuously display "Stranger is typing" to the other person which is kinda a dead giveaway that its a bot and they skip.

How I interact with the text area:
WebElement textArea = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("textarea.chatmsg"));
textArea.sendKeys(message);
I'm currently using chrome driver, and assuming the issue will be the same in the rest.

Any suggestions on how to remove the curser from the text area? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html

You would use selenium's actions class. It's really cool. So you would need to have another element already selected, I'll call this element `other`.

```
Actions actions = new Actions(webDriver);
actions.moveToElement(other).build().perform();
```

Although this doesn't actually move the physical cursor it should be good enough.

Comment: How can be done in Javascript instead?